# How to get the indexes of an element of a nested list of n dimensions

Tags: python, function, nested-lists

I am new at Python (programming in general) and I have some problem that I dont know how to get around.
I have many different nested lists following this pattern:

Listi = [string0, string1, ..., stringn, [list0], [list1], ..., [listn]]

(The list contains a number of strings always positioned at the begining continued by a number of lists always positioned afterwards)

The lists cointained in the first list have the same exact structure as the first list.
The lists can have any number of lists inside them.

What I would like to code is a function that given a random element (a random string) finds the indexes of such element inside the list so that this element can be called from the principal list that contains it.

I would like to get the best possible way to accomplish that in terms of number of operations, but any solution at all would be immensely appreciated.

Heres some example:
Imagine I have this two lists:

```
l1 = ['Node_50', ['Node_48', 'Node_23'], ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]]
l2 = ['Node_50', ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_20']], ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]]
```

I would like to ge a function like this:

```
def functionfinder(list, element):
```

such that:

```
indexes = functionfinder(l1, "Node_40")
```

indexes would be a tuple (2, 2, 1) because:

```
l1[2][2][1] = Node_40
```

Comment: You would have to create a recursive function that keeps track of the current index (e.g. `2, 1, 1`) and go through each list, sublist, subsublist until you find your item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are searching nested lists, a recursive routine would be best. Since you want good speed, the routine should exit as soon as the desired item is found (rather than continuing the search or looking for another one). The following should work if you actually use only lists as your containers for your strings.

```
def functionfinder(asequence, value, indexes_tuple=()):
    for ndx, item in enumerate(asequence):
        if item == value:  
            return indexes_tuple + (ndx,) # found it here: return the answer
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result = functionfinder(item, value, indexes_tuple + (ndx,))
            if result:  
                return result # found it below: stop looking for it
    return ()  # desired value not found yet

l1 = ['Node_50',
      ['Node_48', 'Node_23'],
      ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]
     ]
l2 = ['Node_50',
      ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_20']],
      ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]
     ]

indexes = functionfinder(l1, "Node_40")
print(indexes)
```

The printout from that code is what you want:

```
(2, 2, 1)
```

If you have the `indexes` and you want to access the value that was searched, you could do

```
result = l1
for ndx in indexes:
    result = result[ndx]
```

Now `result` holds the value you searched for.

This code could be generalized to handle other kinds of sequences such as tuples and not just lists. You would need to be careful to not recurse into a string, since Python's strings are also sequences--of characters. You want a tuple as the return value, so my code also uses them. Using an immutable type as the return value does have advantages. But using a mutable type, such as a list, might speed up the execution speed. As it is now, each new list in your parameter requires constructing a complete new tuple of indexes. Using a list could mean that you just need to append a single new index and may speed up the code. Ask if either of those possible improvements appeals to you.

Note that, since Python does not have a built-in immediate way to stop a recursive function, my code uses a returned empty tuple to note that the desired item has not yet been found. When the item is found, a non-empty tuple result is returned which signals all levels of the recursion to stop as soon as possible. This complicates the code somewhat.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed solution this was exacly what I was looking for. Returning tuples works just fine for my circumstances. Thanks!

Comment: Now another question arises: how can I access a list element having the tuple containing its indixes?

Comment: @DanielCasasampera: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Do you know any other way to call the elements of the list having the indexes? I would like to be able to do something like: del l2[0][2], and l2[0][2] = something new

Comment: @DanielCasasampera: If you have the indexes already separated, you can do `l1[2][2][0]`. Those separated brackets are the style for Python itself. The `numpy` module lets you declare arrays so you can use `l1[2, 2, 0]` but that does not work in Python itself.

Comment: I want to be able to do that: l1[2][2][0] but having in mind that I dont know the length of the indexes list. With numpy maybe the solution but I have never use it and if I try to make my nested list a numpy array and then call the array with the list of indexes it gives me an error: too many indices for array

Comment: @DanielCasasampera: I do not understand what you mean in your last comment. You may want to start a new question and explain just what you mean. You could then get a good answer.